# Ordered List RST

Tags: text, restructuredtext

I want do create a list in RST like this:

```
1. text1
2. text2
3. text3

Text...

Text..

4. text4
5. text5
```

But for some reason, the resulting text shows 1. and 2. instead of 4. and 5. It's starting a new list, even thougt I wrote 4. and 5. How to solve this?

Comment: I've copied your example to an online restructuredText Editor and it worked with 4. and 5. You can take a look [here](http://rst.ninjs.org/#MS4gdGV4dDEKMi4gdGV4dDIKMy4gdGV4dDMKClRleHQuLi4KClRleHQuLgoKNC4gdGV4dDQKNS4gdGV4dDU=). I'm quite new to this, so maybe there is something I didn't notice, or maybe you could provide more context?

Comment: You can also indent the text to align with the text of `text3`, and then that text will be indented with that item.

Comment: Solved: Added indent to the text between 3. and 4.